# Exporting a variable in Yocto not working

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, yocto

In one of my recipe, I want to get output of a command in a environmental variable

```
export SDK_IMAGE_VERSION="$(cat ${WORKDIR}/sdk-version.txt)"
```

The output is not as expected, i am getting the WORKDIR expanding, but not output of cat command.

```
export SDK_IMAGE_VERSION="\$(cat /home/aws-mjamal/platform-abc/build-abc-1-prod/tmp/work/abc-poky-linux-gnueabi/sdk-image/1.0-r0/sdk-version.txt)"
```

Can you please guide on what is missing here

Comment: Is this statement inside a task function e.g. do_install()?

Comment: Yes, it is inside install task

Comment: Can you post the complete recipe? Or, a small recipe that reproduces the problem? I can't reproduce it inside a do_install() task